# Vue.js (v3): How to have a unique data-v-* hash for each component instance

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I have the following code:

blah-foo.vue:

```
    <template>
      <div>Hello {{ name }}</div>
    </template>
    
    <script lang="ts">
    import { defineComponent } from 'vue';
    
    export default defineComponent({
      props: {
        name: {
          type: String,
        }
      },
    });
    </script>

   <style scoped>
     div {
       color: white;
     }
   </style>
```

and App.vue:

```
<template>
 <blah-foo
    name="Alice"
  ></blah-foo>
  <blah-foo
    name="Bob"
  ></blah-foo>
</template>
```

The result in my browser is the following:

```
<div data-v-73bdd40c>Hello Alice</div>
<div data-v-73bdd40c>Hello Bob</div>
```

Is there any way I could tell the vue loader to generate an unique `data-v-*` attribute for each of them ?

What is happening in production is that since the component `blah-foo` is called on many different lazy-loaded pages, I end up having many times

```
div[data-v-73bdd40c] {
 color: white;
}
```

all overriding each other.
That isn't a problem in itself, it just does seem very disgraceful (code wise) after having loaded a few pages when inspecting elements.

Comment: A quick solution is to use `v-deep` or `:deep`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**That is not possible with vue-loader. And it shouldn't be done anyway.**
The whole point of the `data-v-xxx` attribute is to identify the components in the DOM so vue can apply to them the correct scoped css.

If it ever applied uniq data-v attributes, it would not be able to apply the correct css.

---

I understand your problem is that, on production, you see in the css inspector several times the css code, right?

My guess is that it's related with sourcemaps, which may mess with the css inspector. But I can't help more without additional details on your project configurations.

Even if your component is used on several pages, its module will be fetched and loaded only once. You don't have the scoped css loaded several times, it's just an inspector problem.